# sharepoint Infopath Forms

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, contenttypes

I am designing infopath form for a list based on content types. Is there a way to add fields to forms without adding to list. I have like 12 different content types for a list. If I add 10 to 20 fields for each content types the list columns number will reach around 150.

Please let me know if there are any other options available? Thank you.

Comment: You will get a good answer and more attention from this community: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is there a way to add fields to forms without adding to list? == Yes, In the above menu bar there is an option to add fields in InfoPath desktop.

Comment: Thanks I will try it